# Why does using probabilities result in higher ROC_AUC scores?

Tags: scikit-learn, model-evaluation, roc

in the most recent playground competition on kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/tabular-playground-series-mar-2021/overview/evaluation) we once again have an evaluation via the area under the roc curve.
When we use the .predict_proba methods (i.e. output probabilities instead of hard values 0, 1) we always get a significantly higher score.

But I do not quite understand how this is works for the ROC AUC metric. It makes sense for log loss as we actually calculate a difference, but does the True positive rate change? I think it shouldn't.
Or is the metric actually doing some subtraction under that hood?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: How are you using log loss? // Do you used AUC as a loss function for training one model and log loss for another model?

Comment: @Dave Hi, no, sorry, I was probably unclear. I mean, it makes sense if the metric were another, like log loss, that predicting probabilities could lead to a lower total loss. But it doesn't make sense for AUC to me.

Comment: To which score is AUC compared, accuracy?

Comment: It is not compared, AUC is the score. Or maybe I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: You mention a "significantly higher score", so "higher" than what?

Comment: I predicted definite classes so 0 or 1. And I got about 0.79 when I used predict_proba which outputs probabilities instead of classes I got 0.88. Which is a much better score. But the ROC shouldn't change I think? So I'm not quite sure how the Area under it could change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120892/discussion-between-dave-and-oliver).